# Como enviar por email<Body> los datos de una vista en MVC 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Buen día

Soy nuevo en el tema de MVC no cuento con mucha experiencia.

Tengo un controlador con el que consulto los registros por medio de una ID, cuando consulto, me muestra los registros almacenados con esa ID, pero ¿cómo puedo enviar esos resultados por correo electrónico al dar click en un botón ?

Este es el controlador con el que consulto los registros del ID

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(decimal? reqid, object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Entities db = new Entities();
    var req = from s in db.TB_CS_TEST
              join st in db.TB_CS_TEST2 on s.REQ_NO equals st.REQ_NO
              where s.REQ_NO.Equals(st.REQ_NO)
              select new SearchModels
              {
                  GetTB1 = s,
                  GetTB2 = st
              };
    if (reqid.HasValue)
    {
        req = req.Where(s => s.GetTB1.REQ_NO == reqid);
    }
    return View(req);
}
```

Esta es mi vista

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication31.Models.SearchModels>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<h2>Search</h2>
  @using (Html.BeginForm()){    
      <p> Request Number: @Html.TextBox("reqid") <br />   
      <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> 
      } 
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Req No</td>
        <td>Item Number</td>
        <td>Item Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>UOM</td>
        <td>Event Date</td>
        <td>Event Place</td>
        <td>Purpose</td>
        <td>Approver 1</td>
        <td>Approver 2</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.GetTB1.REQ_NO</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB1.SEQ_NO</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB1.ITEM_NAME</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB1.QUANTITY</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB1.UOM</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.EVENT_DATE</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.EVENT_PLACE</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.PURPOSE</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.APPROVER1</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.APPROVER2</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.STATUS</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Como pueden ver, mi objetivo es poder enviar los valores de @ item.GetTB1 y @ item.GetTB2 en el cuerpo del email

Soy consciente de que se utiliza un cliente SMPT, pero no se como colocar los datos en el cuerpo  del correo.

Esta es mi función de correo electrónico

```
    public void SendEmail()
{
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("send@email.com", ""); //Usuario ejemplo
    SmtpServer.Port = 25;
    SmtpServer.Host = "154.127.1.150"; // Host de ejemplo
    mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("user@email.com", "email");
    mail.To.Add("user2@email.com");
    mail.Subject = "SUB";
    mail.Body = ""; // ESTO ES LO QUE QUIERO LLENAR CON LA VISTA DEL CONTROLADOR
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

Como puedo enviar esos resultados por email?

Muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: pregunta del millón, ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: He visto ejemplos utilizando la configuracion SMTP , MVC Mailer y Postal pero la mayoria son ejemplos de un formulario para enviar email, lo que yo busco es enviar los datos consultados por email

Comment: Edita la pregunta agregando todo lo que has intentado, revisa este enlace: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Donde llamas a la función `SendEmail()` en el código que has intentado?

Comment: Hola Rafael lo ejecuto antes de return View(req); solo que no lo puse en la pregunta porque solo envia un mensaje comun al correo , ya que no se como llenar el body del mensaje con los datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que el usuario no altera la información que presentada con *Search*. Algo muy sencillo (tal vez no sea lo mejor) podría ser utilizando una variable de sesión.

Básicamente cuando obtienes los datos en tu ActionResult *Search* puedes guardarte el ID en una variable de sesión de esta forma:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    //todo tu código para obtener los datos agregando esto:
    Session["searchID"] = reqid;
}
```

Y luego cuando se ejecuta el envío del email vuelves a obtener la información necesaria.

```
public void SendEmail()
{
    //todo tu código para obtener los datos cambiando lo siguiente
    if (Session["searchID"] != null)
    {
        var reqid = Session["searchID"] as decimal;
        if (reqid.HasValue)
        {
            req = req.Where(s => s.GetTB1.REQ_NO == reqid);
        }
    }
}
```

Por último, para armar el Body podrías crear un método **ToEmailString** en la clase *SearchModels* que pase a string el objetivo con los datos que quieres enviar

```
foreach (SearchModels item in req)
{
    mail.Body = mail.Body + item.ToEmailString();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias la variable de Session si me funciono, ademas tu idea me ayudo a implementar una funcion utilizando StringWriter, muchas gracias @cpistiner!

Comment: Me alegro que sirvió @BlackSD ! Y sí, una genialidad el StringWriter!